# What are the best approach for ANTLR4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am bit new on ANTLR4.
I have full ANTLR4 grammar to parse COBOL source files, but I am bit confuse with my problem :--

1. Performance issue (I also used Prediction.SLL mode but some time it skips some rules)
2. When I provide some different type or new files the always grammar will not be able to parser new files (grammar failure). Always Changes required?
3. I know about YACC, but YACC does not have UI and also not support for Java parser generation.
4. What about Island approach? Where it helps?

OR any other tool should I use?

I wantted to understand ANTLR best way to extract out things, and Is there any other open source tool like ANTLR which will efficient for this purpose.

Your suggestions and guidense are highly appriciated.

Comment: It heavily depends on the design of your grammar when saying problems you met. Thus, if you cannot provide the whole grammar or at least the portions that are important for discussion, I don't think this question will generate any valuable results.

Comment: I know I did not frame my question so well .. But my motive is to understand the Performance issue of ANTLR and also willing to know that is Island have an extra advantage over the Full grammar?..Now Yes I understand that YACC is not a good option against the ANTLR. But Yes I am very curious about to know Is there another tool similar to ANTLR? not YACC.

Comment: Google search and some digging is just a few clicks away. It would be a better way to train yourself up. SO is not a place to replace that kind of learning experience but just for specific things you hit during learning.

Comment: @LexLi  I am confusing between ANTLR is right approach or not? If No what else we have

Answer (score 1):

1. Antlr is very fast without any performance tweaking - it will use SLL where appropriate and automatically fall back to LL if necessary. Fallback is typically encountered in deep recursion analysis - not something to be expected in parsing a simple procedural language like COBOL.
2. A language grammar is typically written to reflect the target language specification. In that case, then no, further changes to the grammar will not be required. If the grammar is written to a subset of the specification, likely you find yourself progressively changing the grammar until it does match the full spec -- unless you can be absolutely certain of the correct 'subset'.
3. So it is not a choice.
4. Antlr supports island grammars directly through lexer modes. This is more than adequate for most purposes. If not for yours, then you need to explain the need more fully.

There are many tools that can do what Antlr does. Which is 'best' depends on the full set of your requirements. To the extent identified in your question, Antlr is as good as any for parsing COBOL.

Comment: So could you please let me know another tools similar to the ANTLR.

Comment: Search for "Antlr alternatives"